# Соединения HTTP Loopback не активированы на данном сервере. (ajax errors)

Tags: wordpress

В админ-панели, плагина "Unyson", раздела "Резервная копия"  появилась ошибка :

> Важно: Соединения HTTP Loopback не активированы на данном сервере. Если вы собираетесь связаться с вашим хостингом, скажите им что когда PHP пытается соединиться обратно к сайту по адресу `https://dc-style.com.ua/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` то он получает ошибку `Неверный ответ JSON`. Может быть проблема с настройками сервера (к примеру локальный DNS, mod_security) которое предотвращает роботу соединенный должным образом.

, что приводит к ошибкам самого плагина, связанные с ajax.

В php.ini строка с "allow_url_fopen" - включена.

Файл admin-ajax.php не отличается от шаблонного, а в файле load-scripts.php ошибка

> scripts.js?ver=2.0.32:50 Ajax error parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 8292

В общем, какие-нибудь советы, что можно сделать ?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Смотри настройки curl

Answer (score 0):

В общем WP как обычно поражает своей "странностью",  не работали некоторые функции из-за плагина отвечающего за перевод "Weglot Translate". Отключил его и всё стало нормально. Спасибо тем, кто смотрел вопрос )

Comment: WP то тут при чем? Кривые плагины и темы - вот источник проблем.